# Exception on calling wait() method of Object class

Tags: java, oop

The below code doesn't execute even after notifying the current thread (using this).

```
public synchronized void test() {
    String str = new String();
    try {
        System.out.println("Test1");
        this.wait();
        this.notifyAll();
        System.out.println("Test2");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        System.out.println("Inside exception");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
 }
```

I get only `Test1` as output on the console.

In, the second case I get the exception if I call the wait method on string object. The reason is because the string class object `str` doesn't hold lock on current object. But I wonder what does `str.wait()` actually means ?

```
public synchronized void test() {
    String str = "ABC";
    try {
        System.out.println("Test1");
        str.wait();
        str.notifyAll();
        System.out.println("Test2");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        System.out.println("Ins");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
 }
```

**Console Output:**

```
> Test1  
java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
```

Answer (score 7):

Not sure what you expected from that code:

1. In your first example, `wait` does what it says: it waits, so `notifyAll` is never called
2. In the second example, you can't call `wait` on an object without holding the monitor of that object first. So you would need to be in a `synchronized(str)` block to avoid the exception. But you would still have the same issue as in 1.

The main use case of `wait` and `notify` is inter-thread communication, i.e. one thread waits and another thread notifies that waiting threads can wake up. In your case the same thread is at both ends of the communication channel which does not work.

Comment: And even if the second example would get a lock on the `str` object, it would result in the same as the first example.

Comment: Now your answer explains it all. +1

Comment: @user1921476 give him kudos by accepting his answer (check mark next to the answer)

Answer (score 3):

you should not call `wait` and `notify` one after the other in the same thread. They should be executed from different threads. If you wait for something, the control is not going further in that thread until some other thread is going to notify it

Answer (score 3):

You should learn how to use `wait()` and `notify()` properly : from Effective Java (Josh Bloch) :

```
// The standard idiom for using the wait method
synchronized (obj) {
    while (<condition does not hold>)
    obj.wait(); // (Releases lock, and reacquires on wakeup)
    ... // Perform action appropriate to condition
}
```

This makes the current thread properly wait for a condition to become true. Other threads should call `notify()` or `notifyAll()` when this condition becomes true.

Yet the more important advice from Josh is : Prefer concurrency utilities to waitand notify

Answer (score 0):

Concerning your first case:
wait causes your current thread to wait until another thread invokes the notify() method or the notifyAll() method. So notify all will never be called unless you do it within another thread.

Answer (score 0):

In your first snippet, the thread is enqueued to wait for the instance when you call `wait`. The `notifyAll` is not executed, because the tread is already waiting.

The notify needs to be executed on another tread.